# Need an alternative to Mobile Broadband API in WinRT

Tags: mobile, mobile-broadband-api

I am trying to use Mobile Broadband API Interfaces to get mobile device information like IMEI,etc., on Windows RT tablet.
[You can find the API reference here](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/desktop/dd323268(v=vs.85).aspx)

I am planning to do a console application to retrieve information as shown in an example below. But I am unable to find the MbnApi namespace in WinRT.

I am aware that it is not available in WinRT. If any of you know or have the Managed Code or DLL for the same, please point me in the right direction.

Code:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;
using System.Text;
using MbnApi;

namespace ConsoleApplication1
{
    class Program
    {
        static void Main(string[] args)
        {
            MbnInterfaceManager mbnInfMgr = new MbnInterfaceManager();
            IMbnInterfaceManager infMgr = (IMbnInterfaceManager)mbnInfMgr;


            MbnConnectionManager mbnConnectionMgr = new MbnConnectionManager();
            IMbnConnectionManager ImbnConnectionMgr = (IMbnConnectionManager)mbnConnectionMgr;


            IMbnConnection[] connections = (IMbnConnection[])ImbnConnectionMgr.GetConnections();
            foreach (IMbnConnection conn in connections)
            {
                IMbnInterface mobileInterface = infMgr.GetInterface(conn.InterfaceID) as IMbnInterface;
                MBN_INTERFACE_CAPS caps = mobileInterface.GetInterfaceCapability();

                MBN_PROVIDER provider = mobileInterface.GetHomeProvider();
                Console.WriteLine("Device Id :" + caps.deviceID);
                Console.WriteLine("DataClass: " + caps.cellularClass);
                Console.WriteLine("Manufacturer: " + caps.manufacturer);
                Console.WriteLine("Model : " + caps.model);
                Console.WriteLine("Firmware Version: " + caps.firmwareInfo);

            }
            Console.ReadKey(true);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: (I changed the title of your question, so that the question will be easier to find, for people who are looking for this information in the future - hope it says what you want to say.)

Answer (score 0):

As you say, Windows Mobile Broadband API is only available on the Windows Desktop.

Here's what you're looking for in the Metro/WinRT area:  [Win RT Mobile Broadband APIs.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/hardware/dn391779.aspx)

There is also some useful information about device enumeration, and other things you might need [here.](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/windows/apps/hh464945.aspx)